# Injecting dependencies in Flask routes without a DI framework

Tags: python, dependency-injection, flask, bootstrap

I was wondering what might be the best way to inject Flask routes dependencies without a DI framework.

I came up with something like this (`CalculationService` being the dependency I want to inject):

```
from typing import Protocol

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class CalculationService(Protocol):
    def calculate(self) -> str:
        '''Returns the result of a calculation'''

class CalculationServiceA:
    def calculate(self) -> str:
        return 'calculation for service A'

class CalculationServiceB:
    def calculate(self) -> str:
        return 'calculation for service B'

def calculate(calculation_service: CalculationService) -> str:
    return calculation_service.calculate()

def calculation_handler_serviceA() -> str:
    return calculate(CalculationServiceA())

def calculation_handler_serviceB() -> str:
    return calculate(CalculationServiceB())

class Context:
    def __init__(self, calculation_service: CalculationService):
        self.calculation_service = calculation_service

    def calculate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.calculation_service.calculate(*args, **kwargs)

handlers_mapping = {
    'A': calculation_handler_serviceA,
    'B': calculation_handler_serviceB,
}
chosen_service = 'A'

context = Context(CalculationServiceA())
context.calculate = handlers_mapping[chosen_service]

@app.route('/calculate')
def calculate_route():
    return context.calculate()
```

For brevity, it is all in one module, in real app I would split the code into different files.

What do you think about such solution? Would it scale well in terms of readability and maintainance?

One benefit that I see immediately is testing: I can test `calculate` directly with some fake `CalculationService` object and can also skip testing the corresponding route (sending requests with Flask client etc.) - would this be a good idea?